# Memory - Pass large dataset from activity to fragments

Tags: android

I have an activity (MainActivity) with 4 fragments (FragmentPagerAdapter) which all requires the same data, a huge collection of objects which are loaded from a local sqlite database (Room) (loading the data could take some seconds). Each fragment displays the **same** collection but **filtered** and each fragment is loaded in memory using `setOffscreenPageLimit(3)` hence I do not want to perform the same queries on each fragment.

At the moment, the collection is asyncronously fetched in the MainActivity and passed in the fragment's `newInstance()` as parcelable objects.
But is this a good approach? My dataset is variable and what if my collection is too large to be handled? Can a parcelable arraylist handle such big values.

Another solution I was thinking of was using a small caching mechanism and injecting my model/manager (that loads/contains the dataset) in the 4 fragments as a single instance using dagger.

What is the best practice/solution to pass huge datasets to their respective fragments? Would you instantiate the fragments beforehand and use an interface to request the data from the activity?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you have a SQLite bbdd, you should use a ContentProvider class.
In the fragment you can implement LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks > with differents id.

```
@Override
     public Loader <List <YourData >> onCreateLoader (int id, Bundle args) {
         return new YourFirstLoader (getActivity (), LOADER_ID);
     }
```

Then create different Loaders that make the request to the content provider, that way they will load the data already filtered.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using Room as the abstraction layer of my sqlite db. It also seems that Loaders are deprecated as of Android P (API 28), and I'm looking for a future-proof solution.

Comment: The loaders aren't deprecated. import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

Comment: "Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28). The recommended option for dealing with loading data while handling the Activity and Fragment lifecycles is to use a combination of ViewModels and LiveData." - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders

Comment: If you are using Room you can create a facade design that only imports the data you need, it is not necessary to bring the complete list and then filter it. You can also use static ArrayList that keep the lists already filtered and empty the ram memory with the complete list.

Comment: Please read this, the Revision 28.0.0 Alpha 1 is from March 2018, you can read that version 4 off Loader was added in version 22.1.0 and belongs to Maven artifact com.android.support:loader:28.0.0-alpha1 : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions